Why has the unwrap button turned into a dropdown menu?
After not having used blender for a few weeks i decided to update it and use it again. For some reason the unwrap button, which you used when you wanted to manually unwrap a 3d model, has turned into a dropdown menu with the options "Angle Based", "Conformal" and "Minimum Stretch". All of these options gave some really bad results and I was wondering if there's a way to go back to the normal "unwrap" option or if this is an irreversible change which occurred after the latest update?
Here's a screenshot of the current dropdown menu:


It's still the same options & methods. The Unwrap was just broken down into more specific options Angle Based, Conformal and with a new option Minimum Stretch but they all still have the same Adjust Last Operation (popup that appears in the lower left corner) panel options with same methods to pick from.

As for the behavior, which I also noticed, these methods seem to produce different results compared to the previous version, but you would need to ask the developers for clarification. This is Q&A site run by volunteers, we are not programmers nor in any way associated with the Blender Foundation, decision making nor development process of the software. For bug reports please see Where to Report a Bug

Angle Based and Conformal are the same as the previous Unwrap, they are just split into two options in the menu now. These were available in previous versions after you run the Unwrap operator:

Only new feature added is Minimum Stretch unwrap algorithm.

Is there any way to reverse it?

@AboutTripod48 Yes, use a previous version of Blender. No seriously, this is just how the tool is working now. It's not the first tool that has been changed and it won't be the last.

Martynas: Glad you mention it. I even saw a tutorial on YT where they showed this new unwrapping menu and the tutor stated, Angle Based was how it worked in older versions and now we have two new options, Conformal and Minimum Stretch. I wondered if he ever bothered to check the unwrapping options in older versions.

@AboutTripod48 There is nothing to reverse. The operator is the same, the only thing that changed was that another method was added. The previous methods should work identically. It's possible to override the menu with Python if that's what you are asking to make it the same, but just making a hotkey or adding whatever option to your Quick Favourites manu makes a whole lot more sense.

Right click on the Button you want > Add to quick favorites

@GordonBrinkmann It mildly bothers me that hitting U two times doesn't work anymore though :D I thought that was nice. Well... what you gonna do?.. Not a big deal.

And creating a hotkey with U set to double click doesn't seem to work :/ But maybe I just didn't try hard enough.

I guess there is a change in semantics now, because when you now say "unwrap", this includes all the other options in the menu, but it is usual amongst Blender users to mean unwrapping method that uses seams by that term... That's a bit problematic and may cause some confusion since that term is probably used this way in many existing tutorials for previous versions... Well... It's progress. The new algorithm is still very nice to have and it does make sense to separate the methods and the menu does look more tidy now...
